# halachic definition of Zera

Tags: halacha, sexuality

When a couple is having intimate relations, during foreplay, is the clear liquid that emits from the male organ considered Zera? Is a wife permitted to stimulate the male organ knowing that these pre ejaculate emissions are inevitable?

Comment: Seems like two questions. Motion to close as Too Broad (if the community decides it's on topic).

Comment: It's only one question.....pre ejaculate fluid, as far as zera li'vatala is concerned....is it semen, or is it not?

Comment: If that's your question, why not just ask it, instead of the two different question currently in this post?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%92_%D7%90

Comment: @DoubleAA these two questions are very closely linked. IMO, it's reasonable to look for an answer that addresses both in one compact discussion.

Comment: @IsaacMoses What does a discussion of Avot haTumah have to do with laws of Tzniut?

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn't the second sentence indicate pretty clearly that the first sentence is aiming toward the latter rather than the former?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Even were it so, the latter question stands independant of the answer to the former question. If the answer to the former question is no, then we can still ask from the perspective of Hilkhoth Tzniyut, and if it is yes, we can still ask from the perspective of davar sheino mitkavein, a women's obligation in pru urvu, what is used and what is levatalla, etc. I don't know how you think these are the same.

Comment: @DoubleAA set aside your assumption that the first sentence could be about *hilchot tum-a*. If you want, [edit] the question to make it clear that it isn't. What you're left with is a question the OP wants an answer to, preceded by one point of uncertainty that feeds into it, of which the author is aware. The question doesn't need to include every point of *halachic* uncertainty that any reader/editor may think of.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21565&st=&pgnum=407