# Teshuva related to Pgam HaBrit

Tags: halacha, sexuality

If pre-ejaculate fluid is released prior to intercourse (while kissing etc), does a person have to do teshuva? Pre-jaculate can contain but typically doesn’t contain semen.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62541/759